# Should I set any attribute for the optional fields in case of JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Should I set any attribute for the optional fields in case of JSON.NET deserialization? I mean something like

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public String foo { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only if this is getting deserialized? I'm missing a use case here. Try to add some more info to your question.

Comment: @Davio I need to deserialize object of this class that could have this field or don't have it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your class has a property that the JSON does not, then that property will have a default value in your class after deserialization.  If your JSON has a property that your class does not, then Json.Net will simply ignore that property during deserialization.  You do not need to do anything special to handle it.

You can write simple test code to prove this out.  Here we have a class `Foo` which has properties `A` and `C`, while the JSON we want to deserialize has properties `A` and `B`.  When we deserialize, we see that A is populated, B is ignored (not in the class) and C has a default value of null (not in the JSON).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""A"" : ""one"", ""B"" : ""two"" }";

        Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("A: " + (foo.A == null ? "(null)" : foo.A));
        Console.WriteLine("C: " + (foo.C == null ? "(null)" : foo.C));
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A: one
C: (null)
```

Comment: Thanks! And what should I do when I don't want to serialize some fields to the JSON if they are equals to the default values? Should I use [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)] in this case?

Comment: Use `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]` on that property.  (Or you can set this globally in `JsonSerializerSettings`.)

Comment: I have a JSON element that sometimes appears in the JSON and has a value associated with it. I have a if condition built on that value but it fails because sometimes it doesn't appear in JSON but it is there in my class. I am using this null check: [JsonProperty("proxyBaseUrl", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]     but I still run into an exception when I am trying ot get it's value and it doesn't exist in my JSON. How to get around this?

Comment: @Monnie_tester Please post this as a new question, and then we can help you better.  That way you can fully explain what you are trying to do, show your classes, etc., and more people will see it.  In the new question you can provide a link back to this one if it helps provide context.  Thanks.